# The presentShareDialogWithLink won't present the dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to present Facebook share dialog in my app using `presentShareDialogWithLink`:

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                          handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error)         {
...

}];
```

I'm following the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share) and using Facebook iOS SDK 3.17. Everything seems to be set up correctly. However nothing happens and the handler never gets called. I'm running on iPhone 5 with Facebook app installed.

And yes, I have the openURL method in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                          sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                            fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                            }];

  return urlWasHandled;
}
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

P.S. After some time I get this in the log output:

```
access_token:       ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED
```

Can it be the problem? The full log is [here](http://pastebin.com/PVree6PH).

Comment: You don't need an access token to use the presentShareDialogWithLink method. Generally you should wrap a present* method with a canPresent* method as there are a variety of failure scenarios, including but not limited to: your app not being properly configured (lacking plist entries, for example), or the Facebook app being out of date, etc. Try the HelloFacebook sample app (post a status update without logging in). If that works, then it's likely an app misconfiguration.

Comment: @MingLi, actually I have the canPresent* but removed from sample code to make it simple. The actual code that I use is here https://gist.github.com/grigy/e69835828d6495cb2c35

Comment: Your code looks OK, which makes me think there might be a configuration issue. Can you running the HelloFacebook sample as I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, the HelloFacebook sample worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed. I had an incorrcted `fb<ID>` value in the .plist file, under "URL types" > "URL Schemes".